# Force Terraform to destroy all, even if nothing changed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

1. I want to put code in `main.tf` to force Terraform to destroy and recreate every instance on each apply, even if nothing has changed.
2. I need the same, but only if `user_data_sh.tpl` changes.
3. Same, but if anything in `user_data` changes.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What, you want to destroy everything on each apply? I mean for that you only need to do `terraform destroy`, no matter what the change is and where.

Comment: In addition to @MarkoE said, you can also just do that within an autoscaling group. Set desired Instances to 0 with your 1st apply. Then set desired instances to X on 2nd apply. You can do that anytime you update user-data as well.